# Как в библиотеке telebot выполнять действия, через определенный промежуток времени

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Нужно создать бота, который показывает расписание для лицея. Так как в данном лицее 2-ух недельное расписание, то нужно каждые 7 дней эту неделю переключать. Меня интересует, как выполнить это действие, каждые 7 дней? Я слышал, про какой-то "крон", но так и не понял, что это. Язык python, библиотека telebot.

Comment: крон -- это утилита для создания расписания для выполнения скриптов. Для винды есть планировщик заданий. А так, вы можете создать дополнительный поток и запускать его раз в n-дней, а тот поток например сделает парсинг расписания и сохранит его в базу вашего бота. Вчитался в вопрос... если расписание не меняется, а только меняется номер недели, то ничего не нужно дополнительного делать -- просто при запросе к боту возьмите текущую дату и у него номер недели: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python

Comment: А можно пожалуйста ссылку на информацию о кронах?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Спасибо, большое